# How to replace Url and href with javascript function

Tags: javascript, iphone, url, titanium, href

What i want is to remove the event of opening a new page, handle the url with a javascript function so the href is not workin.

Im using titanium appcelerator to make an iPhone app, well its finished but this is an update.
Anyway, i have an webView so i can show hyperlinks, but when i click on this link it opens up a page inside that same webView.

Which is where the problem starts, i need to catch the event of opening the url and call a function to open a new webView or safari with the given url.

Im not really that great in html/js/regex, thats why im running into this problem.

Here is an test case:
1. the html is containing an url without href, this must be made clickable so i can open the url.
2. the html is containing an url with href, this must not open the url but use a js function
3. the html is containing url with and without href, both need to be clickable and call a js function to open the url in a new webView or safari.

I think that clears up what im expecting to achieve,

here is my code containing the functions i have now for these cases, but the first function works if there is no case 2. And the second function is not calling the event... replacing by just a function also does not work.

[Test case](http://pastebin.com/KAVNkWbP)

Hope someone can help me out with this

Comment: are you able to catch the click event of your webview in your titanium app?

Comment: yes, i can catch a click on the webview.

Comment: are you also getting the url?

Comment: no that is not possible, it just registered a click

Comment: you need to get the url so that you may proceed with that url. Do you use regular exp to get the url in html.

Comment: I saw you are doing html_code = html_code.replace(/<a /gi, "<a onClick='Ti.App.fireEvent(\"openMyBrower\", {url: this.href}); return false;'"); And you are saying that you are unable to get this.href value.

Comment: the event i want to fire, is not fired. The this.href returns nothing i think.

Comment: Also that regex adds an onclick, but the href still will open the page. The href needs to be replaced so it wont open page.

Comment: Did you check the html? Were you able to add the event in html?

Comment: The event doesn't fire if it is not properly placed in the html

Comment: Try to alert the html to see if click event is there in the html.

Comment: yes the event is there in the html,the onclick is added just fine, but the event that needs to be called is not called for some reason

Comment: the sample html is in the test case, that html is what i run through the functions. The outcome is: hi hello... first one <a onClick='Ti.App.fireEvent("openMyBrower", {url: this.href}; return false;" href='http://google.nl'>http://google.nl</a>

Comment: This will be solved once you place the onclick event in html perfectly. I had the same issue which was resolved after placing some quotes "".

Comment: Hey I am running in the same problem:(

Comment: Please let me know the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok that is just so dumb of me, the html did not have a start nor end. As in the example of brian, in code its saying it needs to include javascript in the html. Which it does not do by default. Added 2 lines to my html and the function works

Now i just need an REGEX which checks if an url has an href, if so add function. If not add href and function.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/819929), if nothing else it's a great starting point on your issue.

Comment: this is a good file, but it does not do what i want. Which is open the links in a new window through a titanium function.